# Volume of Revolution Bounds

Tags: calculus, integration, volume

The question is : Find the volume of the solid obtained by rotating about the $y$-axis the region bounded by the curves $y= e^{-2x^2}$, $y=0$, $x=0$, $x=1$.

Should the bounds for the problem be taken from the $y$-axis or the $x$-axis?

I think that the integral for this problem would be:

$$\prod\int(e^{-2x^2})^2\,dx,$$

or do i have to rewrite the equation in terms of x?

Answer (score 1):

For a solid of revolution about the $y$ axis, the integral looks like

$$\pi \int_{e^{-2}}^1 dy \: (x(y))^2 = \frac{\pi}{2} \int_{e^{-2}}^1 dy \: (-\log{y})$$

Comment: where does the x come from?

Comment: The $x$ comes from the fact that we are integrating thin disks of radius $x$ that make up our volume.

Comment: You dont have to rewrite the equation to make it x = ...?

Comment: the bound is e^-2 and not 0?

Comment: do the bound stay the same?

Comment: Yes, the bounds are correct; at $x=1$, $y=e^{-2}$.

Comment: why is it e^-2? I was thinking that it would be 0. and how do you get the exponent like that? i tried doing $e^-2$ but that doesnt seem to do it.

Comment: The bound is $x=1$, plug that in for $y$.  And for the exponent, you have to use braces when the exponent is more than a single character.

Comment: @RossMillikan: $x^2 = -\frac{1}{2} \log{y}$.  See above.

Comment: Sorry, brain glitch